# no function clause matching in ProyectWeb.PageLiveView.handle_info/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

I don't know how I can match my asynchronous function and my handle_info

this code works:

```
def order_month() do
    Task.async(fn ->
      (1..12)
      |> Enum.map(fn a -> %{months: a} |> Map.put(:order_months, Proyect.BuyHandler.order_month(a |> Integer.to_string()) 
      |> Enum.map(fn m -> m |> Proyect.BuyHandler.get_opc() end))end)
      end)


  end
```

my intention is to receive it this way:

```
def handle_info({_ref, %{months: month, order_months: order_months}}, socket) do
   {:noreply, assign(socket, %{months: month, order_months: order_months} )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Task.async/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async/1) is designed to yield results with [`Task.await/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html?#await/2).

Whether you want to receive results back with `handle_info/2`, you should explicitly send the results from the spawned (e. g. with [`Kernel.spawn/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#spawn/1)) process to the parent process.

You have not shown the code of `Proyect.BuyHandler.get_opc/1`, but if we assume it does a simple transformation, we might send the message from there (`Task.start/1` should be used instead of `Task.async/1` in such a case to start the process unlinked.) Somewhat along these lines would work.

```rb
def order_month(pid) do
  Task.start(fn ->
    (1..12)
    |> Enum.map(fn a ->
      %{months: a,
        order_months: Proyect.BuyHandler.order_month("#{a}")}
    end)
    |> Enum.map(&Proyect.BuyHandler.get_opc/1)
    # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ THIS ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    |> Enum.each(&send(pid, &1))
  end)
end
```

---

`handle_info/2` itself should probably have a signature `def handle_info(%{}}, socket)` in such a case.